# Backend for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need a backend to store location updates and messages, I was thinking of using JSON to connect to the Amazon S3 server and to fetch and store data.

How many clients could be connected to this server? Is there a way to link a MYSQL server to Amazon S3 for login and users accounts?

Comment: I suspect you are referring to ec2. S3 is just an object store. It does not execute code.

Comment: @datasage so ec2 for backend and would linking that to s3 be possible?

Comment: S3 is good for storing large pieces of data. If its small you could use dynamodb or a mysql database. But you will have to write a back end application (which will run on ec2) to which your iOS app will communicate. While its possible to connect to a database directly from an iOS, its generally not a good idea in most senarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is not a database store; you write/delete/replace an entire object.

You want AWS RDS. Amazon manages the DB (MySQL supported). Skim the reference architectures for something applicable to your needs. Scale them down; they're designed to make use of as many AWS services as possible.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/

Comment: To store data from lets say 1000 users from around the world, would it be better to use Amazon Dynamo DB or AWS RDS?

Answer (score 1):

Other option is Amazon Dynamo DB. This is an infinite-scale nosql db with a fully managed REST API. You dont worry about the data size growth, speed etc. AWS take care of all these. 
http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/.
Even in this case, you need to have some code running in the backend, which receives your REST calls from the iOS and writes to the Dynamo.

Other even easier solutions are https://parse.com/ and https://www.firebase.com/
These are solutions specifically for your kind of needs - Make a mobile backend Datastore. They give client SDK, which has a very great value in terms of offline synch. You just invoke the SDK from the apps and will synch with the backend datasore when the connections are available - reduces your code complexity a lot !

Comment: To store data from lets say 1000 users from around the world, would it be better to use Amazon Dynamo DB or AWS RDS?

Comment: 1000 is a small number - Either choice would work. Dynamo is easier to use here (if you dont have rich query needs) - zero maintenance support. Even easier is Parse (above).

Comment: If I chose to use Parse/Firebase, would I need to manually code the CDN to fetch and store location updates and messages (similiar to Whatsapp type of messages)?

Comment: @Moe, I think I didnt fully understand your question on CDN. These services makes it easy for you to store and retrieve data with only client (app) side code. These are specifially targeted at people who are not very familar with server side, but wanted to have a remote data store.

Comment: If i wanted to store location updates and messages between two people and group chats, could this be done?

Comment: I think you could. Now if it is like whatsapp, then 1000 "users" is not the volume of data, but the amount of messages they exchange. I guess you are up for a large load. You need to look into the load handling, price etc. I know that DynamoDB scales well here - you also dont need to worry about partitioning data when it grows. Now since you know all the options, you can experiment/read more on it.

Comment: Would it be possible to create individual user profiles and store their data for each user that signs up and uses the application? I've had a quick search around and read about joining AWS Elastic Beanstalk and AWS Identity and Access Management to the DynamoDB. Would this be possible or am I going the wrong way about it?

Also I've been looking at using a communication core between my front end and backend, I know that WhatsApp uses Yowsup but I wondering if there was an alternative to Yowsup - or would I need to build my own?